# In need of best font colour

Tags: font

Can someone help with the font colours for my poster which has an image with combination of white colour and shadow and different shades of black

Comment: Show us the poster.

Answer (score 1):

To choose the best color, you need to think about some aspects:

- what you want to express (joy, sadness);
- it is the message more important than the image, it is the central element?
- with black and white, any color can be used, but is important too if the predominant color is the first or the second one.

Your poster's color palette may be defined by using a custom palette suited to your brand or an event.

If the text is the most important, the color palette should include sufficient contrast between different elements.